# Call function named clearState? (java/android beginner)

Tags: java, android

Here's the code:

```
public CellState(Context context, GameState state) {
    super(context);

    setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(70, 70));
    setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
    setClickable(true);

    mGameState = state;

    //TODO: call clearState
}
```

So I have to call clearState, which has already been written. This is from a java/android intro tutorial and I've never programmed before so I've been slogging through. Any help on what to do to call clearState would be appreciated.

clearState code:

```
public void clearState() {
    mState = EMPTY;
}
```

Comment: Could you post code for the `clearState()` function?

Comment: I added it to the end of the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write this in place of your comment:

```java
clearState();
```

Functions are called by first writing the name of the function, then parenthesis, and ; in the end. If the function takes any parameters, then those go inside the parenthesis, multiple params separated with commas.

Comment: Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: :) "May the first steps be light on you"